# Magento custom module with custom database table admin page

Tags: magento

I have followed a wiki post to setup a custom module with a custom database table.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

One thing that I can't work out is how to display a list of database entries in the admin backend. Any ideas about what I'm missing would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Code is simple method to view your custom table datas in admin panel

Admin view for your custom module :

Create the below path in your module :

```
/app/code/local/<Namespace>/<Module>/etc/adminhtml.xml
```

in **adminhtml.xml** file contain below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <[module] module="[module]">
            <title>[Module]</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <items module="[module]">
                    <title>Manage Items</title>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>[module]/adminhtml_[module]</action>
                </items>
            </children>
        </[module]>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <[module]>
                        <title>[Module] Module</title>
                        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    </[module]>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>   
    </acl>
    <layout>
        <updates>
```

Create the Adminhtml folder and create Controller.php file

```
/app/code/local/<Namespace>/<Module>/controllers/Adminhtml/<Module>Controller.php
```

in `<Module>Controller.php` file contain below content

```
<?php 
class <Namespace>_<module>_Adminhtml_<module>Controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
            $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu('<module>/items');
            $this->renderLayout();

    }   

}
```

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/.xml

in `<module>.xml` file contain below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <[module]_adminhtml_[module]_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="domain" template="[module]/[module].phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </[module]_adminhtml_[module]_index>
</layout>
```

Create the new folder in below path

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/<module>/<module>.phtml
```

in `<module>.phtml` file contain below content

```
<?php

// Write your custom table Collection Here

?>
```

Comment: Great responses! Managed to find issue whereby I had to add '$this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('[module]/adminhtml_[module]'));' to the IndexController and remove that same line from [Module]Controller. Tried viewing the module on the frontend with no luck. Have tried 'http://magento.domain.local/module' and 'http://magento.domain.local/module/index/index'. Keep getting 'HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error)'. Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to view your module url look like http://domain_name.com/module_name/controller_name/action_name

Comment: if you get 500 internal server error, Modify your memory_limit to minimum 128M in your php.ini file..

Comment: tried module url & memory limit is set to 128M - no luck so far

Comment: Contact your host provide still if you get 500 internal server error.

Comment: the above example is missing router section in config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Well, to display database entries in the admin backend, you'll need to do the following things:
- Create a router for admin backend controller. THis can be done via the config.xml file
- Create a controller 
- Create a grid container block
- Create a grid block. In this Grid block, you can specify which columns... you want to add to the list

You can follow the following tutorials:

1. http://markshust.com/2012/07/05/creating-magento-adminhtml-grids-simplified
2. http://www.webspeaks.in/2010/08/create-admin-backend-module-in-magento.html

Magento admin is quite complex, the best way to learn it is to look at the existing code such as how Magento display product list...